# Booting Ubuntu takes ages with system file check

Tags: boot, filesystem

[image: Booting ubuntu]

I have been using ubuntu 20.04 now. Every time I try to boot into Ubuntu, it starts with a filesystem check (I'm not sure if that's what it is), as in in the image attached, which takes atleast 5-6 minutes before the user login appears. Earlier I used to dual boot with windows 10, I assumed that could be the problem, but I tried installing only ubuntu and the problem still persists. I also tried reinstalling the grub but that too didn't help. I have got all hardware requirements satisfied. This behaviour wasn't there when I first installed Ubuntu 20.04, but it appeared after installing for the 3rd time. I think there's a bug introduced with an update.[image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Are you booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, or Ubuntu installed on a USB flash drive, or Ubuntu installed on an internal SSD/HDD? Do you know how to run `fsck`? The image you show is not a file system check... it's a log of the startup process. Does it stop at a certain point, or show any errors? Take a picture of that...

Comment: Including the output of `systemd-analyze blame` in your original question will be helpful also. Please [edit] your question and add the extra info.

Answer (score 1):

### Removing Disk Check From 20.04 Boot

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check when booting Ubuntu 20.04.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` may still come up but fsck will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the `linux line` in grub.cfg just before `quiet splash`

It is recommended to add the command to grub.cfg by editing /etc/default/grub thus: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.mode=skip quiet splash"` and then run `sudo update-grub`.

I have had this problem with a Live USB but not with an installed system.